# How to deal with dehydrating medicine

Tags: side-effects, allergy, urine, dehydration

If a person is dehydrated by something that cannot be gotten rid of, and drinking a lot of water solves some parts of dehydration but not others, due to losing the water by freqent urination, what might be some potential treatments to look into or ask the doctor about?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [How To Ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [meta]. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: Okay, thank you. After I've looked at the links you shared, can I recover the lost reputation points by deleting this post?

Comment: @CareyGregory How is this now?

Comment: Much better, thank you. I retracted my close vote and your reputation points have been restored.

Comment: The ways to keep appropriate fluid volume vary based on cause.  Advice for one cause could kill you if it's a different cause. This is too close to an advice request, otherwise too broad.

Comment: @doctorwhom Is there something in meta about the difference between advice requests and the kind of questions that should be asked?

Comment: See the meta post linked above.  It's hard to understand sometimes why something is individualized, but in health, it often is.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Yes, I read that meta post. I would say that this question currently is not too individualized, but that it may well be a type of question or one asked in such a way that the natural answer consists of advice. And in the process of implementing that meta post to bring this to its current state, I indeed made it more broad. How then would you describe a post that is neither broad nor individualized?

Comment: Good question, and I'm not sure there is an easy answer to that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excessive urination (more than 3 liters of urine per day) is medically called [polyuria](https://www.msdmanuals.com/professional/genitourinary-disorders/symptoms-of-genitourinary-disorders/polyuria).

Causes include:

- Excessive drinking
- Taking diuretic pills
- Diabetes mellitus
- Diabetes insipidus due to various brain or kidney disorders

A doctor will want to know:

- What is an estimated amount of urine per day?
- Any other symptoms, such as hunger, fatigue, etc.?
- When did the problem start?

The doctor will then likely order various blood and urine tests to check for diabetes mellitus and other disorders. The doctor needs to make a diagnosis first, so at this point there is not much to discuss. The doctor can tell how much to drink.